# Scroll-to-end in VS2012 output window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

While an app is running, I get a flood of information being written to the output window (which is good), and this window auto-scrolls to the end so that you always see the latest message written.

If something interesting appears in the output window, I select it to pause the auto-scroll to further analyse that message.

After I'm done, I'd like to resume the auto-scroll functionality. How do I switch auto-scroll back on again?

Comment: You have to move the caret to bottom.  Type Ctrl+End.

Comment: OK, that did it. Thanks. I'd tried clicking on the bottom on the page before, and obviously got close the the end of the file but just not exactly at the end. Change your comment to an answer and I'll mark it answered

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To re-enable autoscrolling, while in the output window just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd>.

Comment: @kroimon I swear I tried that and it didn't take, but it worked this time, which is great news because I'm on a Mac Book Pro ergo no "end" key.

Comment: Why isn't there a button to do this...?

Comment: @Coops why there **still** isn't a button to do this...